# Отложенный alert

Tags: javascript

На странице при загрузке выводится сообщение

```
        <script>
            alert("Message");
        </script>
```

плюс на странице есть другие скрипты (слайдер, выпадающее меню).
Как сделать так, чтобы alert выполнялся только после того, как будут загружены все остальные скрипты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если используется jQuery, то `$(function(){alert('Message');})`
Если нет - то в помощь `window.onload`

Comment: да, уже сделано через window.onload

Answer (score 2):

Перед закрывающим тегом </body> поставьте этот код, к тому моменту по крайней мере будет пройден весь документ, однако далеко не факт, что всё будет прогружено.

Answer (score 1):

[MDN : On page load snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/On_page_load)